# Multi-threaded transactional kafka producer - should I flush before close?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Let's consider multithreaded transnational kafka producer. Should I `flush()` producer before closing?  In other words, does Transactional producer buffers in batches data before sending them ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [javadocs](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

> Applications don't need to call flush method for transactional
>   producers, since the commitTransaction() will flush all buffered
>   records before performing the commit

This is best illustrated in the javadoc example

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("transactional.id", "my-transactional-id");
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());

producer.initTransactions();

try {
 producer.beginTransaction();
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
 producer.commitTransaction();
} catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException e) {
 // We can't recover from these exceptions, so our only option is to close the producer and exit.
 producer.close();
} catch (KafkaException e) {
 // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
 producer.abortTransaction();
}
producer.close();
```

In short it is better to use transactional APIs of the producer (which are blocking and will throw exceptions on failure).

Further, in case of multithreaded application, you would need to ensure that there is only one open transaction per producer. And if at all you get an exception during the transaction, you should call `producer.abortTransaction()` (also highlighted in the example) to maintain the **exactly once semantics** of the producer's transactional capabilities.